# Maximal chromatic polynomial of a graph with fixed chromatic number

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Consider all the graphs with $n$ vertices and whose chromatic number is $k$, note that the graph does not have to be connected. What are the graphs with the maximal chromatic polynomial among those graphs?
I think that the answer should be the graphs consisting of a $k$-clique plus $n-k$ isolated vertices, is it true? How to prove this?

Comment: How do you define a maximal polynomial?

Comment: maximal in terms of the grahp with maximum number of colorings

Comment: This problem is still unsolved and was stated independently by Wilf and Linial. please cheek this paper : Loh, P. S., Pikhurko, O., & Sudakov, B. (2010). Maximizing the number of q‐colorings. Proceedings of the London Mathematical Society, 101(3), 655-696.

Comment: @W.R.P.S The unsolved problem is over all $n$-vertex graphs with $m$ edges, without fixing the chromatic number - the version of the problem in this question seems easier.